# Admad Social Auth route cannot be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, social-authentication

I want to integrate social auth with login and signup in cakephp for which I have used Admad-social-auth plugin.The plugin is working totally fine on local wamp but gives error on server. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Error: A route matching "array ( 'prefix' => false, 'plugin' => 
'ADmad/SocialAuth', 'controller' => 'Auth', 'action' => 'login', 'provider' => 
'google', '?' => array ( 'redirect' => NULL, ), '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be 
found.
```

https://puu.sh/DDXNf/d35d9cdbb8.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that there is no route matching `ADmad/SocialAuth`, I suspect this is happening during page rendering (i.e. when trying to "calculate" a button's link).

Most probably you haven't "registered" the plugin with Cake. To do that, add the below line to your cakephp bootstrap file (`config/bootstrap.php`)?

```
Plugin::load('ADmad/SocialAuth', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);
```